# Actualizar automáticamente la gráfica después de cambiar uno de los parámetros con dat.gui

Tags: javascript, plot

Grafiqué una función en 3D usando plotly.js y agregue un controlador con dat.gui que modifica uno de los parámetros de la función, el problema es que cuando modifico el parámetro de la función me hace una nuevo gráfico encimado al anterior, en su lugar debería ir modificando la gráfica a medida que voy modificando manualmente el parámetro. Seguramente es algo que escribo mal en el código, espero puedan ayudarme.
Muchas gracias.

Comment: como tu dijiste, "Seguramente es algo que escribo mal en el código", es por eso que tienes que poner el codigo de lo contrario no sabremos que haces mal

Comment: Christian agrego el código, no pude cargarlo la primera vez que escribí en el foro, estoy aprendiendo a usarlo. Para poder correrlo se necesita el dat.gui.js, es muy largo por eso no lo subí. Pero dejo la dirección de donde lo descargue: github.com/dataarts/dat.gui/tree/master/build. Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <head>
    <script src='https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js'></script>
    <script src="dat.gui.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id='myDiv'></div>
<script >

var button_layer_1_height = 1.2
var button_layer_2_height = 1.1
var annotation_offset = 0.04


    //Defino parámetro a controlar con dat.gui      
    var params = {
                G: 0.1,
                
            };

var zPts = []; 
var xPts = [];
var yPts = [];
  //Control GUI

  var gui = new dat.GUI();

   
  var updateGraphFunc = function(){

for(x=-3; x<=3; x+= 0.01) {
  let zdat = [];
  let ydat = [];
  let xdat = [];
  for (y=0; y<=0.5; y+=0.01) {
    zdat.push( 2*0.125*[Math.sqrt(2/ (Math.PI* (params.G**2 + (y**2 / params.G**2)))) * Math.exp(-2*((x**2)+0.25) / [params.G**2 + (y**2/params.G**2)])] * [Math.cosh(2*x/(params.G**2 + (y**2/params.G**2))) + Math.cos( (2*x*y) / params.G**4 + y**2)]);
    ydat.push(y);
    xdat.push(x);
  }
  zPts.push(zdat);
  yPts.push(ydat);
  xPts.push(xdat);
  }

var data = [{
    z: zPts,
    x: xPts,
    y: yPts,
    type: 'surface',
    colorscale:'Jet',
    contours: {
    z: {
      show:true,
      usecolormap: true,
      highlightcolor:"#42f462",
      project:{z: true}
    }
  }
 
  }];  
  Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
  }
  
  var updateGraph = function() { updateGraphFunc(); }
  var updatemenus=[
    {
        buttons: [
            {
                args: ['type', 'surface'],
                label: '3D Surface',
                method: 'restyle'
            },
            {
                args: ['type', 'contour'],
                label:'Contour',
                method:'restyle'
 
            }
        ],
        direction: 'left',
        pad: {'r': 10, 't': 10},
        showactive: true,
        type: 'buttons',
        x: 0.15,
        xanchor: 'left',
        y: button_layer_2_height,
        yanchor: 'top'
    },

    {
        buttons: [
            {
                args: ['colorscale', 'Viridis'],
                label: 'Viridis',
                method: 'restyle'
            },
            {
                args: ['colorscale', 'Electric'],
                label:'Electric',
                method:'restyle'
            },
            {
                args: ['colorscale', 'Earth'],
                label:'Earth',
                method:'restyle'
            },
            {
                args: ['colorscale', 'Hot'],
                label:'Hot',
                method:'restyle'
            },
            {
                args: ['colorscale', 'Portland'],
                label:'Portland',
                method:'restyle'
            },
            {
                args: ['colorscale', 'Blackbody'],
                label:'Blackbody',
                method:'restyle'
            },
        ],
        direction: 'left',
        pad: {'r': 10, 't': 10},
        showactive: true,
        type: 'buttons',
        x: 0.15,
        xanchor: 'left',
        y: button_layer_1_height,
        yanchor: 'top'
    },
]
var annotations = [
    {
      text: 'Trace type:',
      x: 0,
      y: button_layer_2_height - annotation_offset,
      yref: 'paper',
      align: 'left',
      showarrow: false
    },
    {
      text: 'Colorscale:',
      x: 0,
      y: button_layer_1_height - annotation_offset,
      yref: 'paper',
      align: 'left',
      showarrow: false
    },
]

  var layout = {
    autosize: false, 
    width: 1300,
    height: 600,
    margin: {t: 130, b: 0, l: 0, r: 0},
    updatemenus: updatemenus,
    annotations: annotations,
    scene: {
        xaxis:{
            gridcolor: 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
            zerolinecolor: 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
            showbackground: true,
            backgroundcolor:'rgb(230, 230,230)'
        },
        yaxis: {
            gridcolor: 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
            zerolinecolor: 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
            showbackground: true,
            backgroundcolor: 'rgb(230, 230, 230)'
        },
        zaxis: {
            gridcolor: 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
            zerolinecolor: 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
            showbackground: true,
            backgroundcolor: 'rgb(230, 230,230)'
        },
        aspectratio: {x: 1, y: 1, z: 0.7},
        aspectmode: 'manual'
  }
  };
  
  
  var folder0 = gui.addFolder('Parameters');
        var GGUI= folder0.add(params, 'G').onChange(updateGraphFunc);
            folder0.open();
        


        // onChange or onFinishChange

       
        gui.open();
    
    // do this last so all structures are set up, all parameters defined
    updateGraphFunc();
  



</script>
</body>
```